Setting up venv environment in tumbleweed
I have recently installed opensuse tumbleweed coming from Ubuntu (KDE Neon) and needed to install a python package. pip returned This environment is externally managed and I understand that the best practice is to create a virtual environment with venv. Activating this, I installed numpy and matplotlib but pyplot plots returned UserWarning: FigureCanvasAgg is non-interactive, and thus cannot be shown and after looking a but into plotting backends I thought there might be a quicker way as this works in the default system environment.
So I did pip freeze > requirements.txt from the system environment, activated a new fresh environment and did pip install -r requirements.txt. Several packages could not be resolved and they seemed to be installed from zypper. They also did not seem releated to my task at hand so I commented them out and finished the install. However, the backend problem of matplotlib remained.
I have primarily been on ubuntu-based distributions with conda environments the last many years and my task at hand has so far occured to me to be could straightforward. I still have several things to try related to the actual matplotlib problem (or installing my package with pip) but my main thought after all of this is: What is the most straightforward way to create a new environment where I can install my necessary packages and get matplotlib showing figures? In particular in a tumbleweed scope
